# How to transform a quote into an order from CALLBACK HOOKS, MAGENTO 2.3

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, quote, order-grid

I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway. And they provide a callback hooks i've set for them to return me the CartID (Quote's entity_id).

But from here on, it feels like it isnt right for me to call guest API, as the cart belongs to an actual customer's cart. Neither do i have the access tokens when the callback hook is being sent to the API i've created.

How can i create the order (sales_order table & sales_order_grid) based on the quote i could receive ?

Please advise what should i do as im stuck on this for 3 days.